# ModbusSlaveApp on C#

Tags: c#, client, modbus, slave

[Multiway.Slave mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7plKA.png)

On the screen Multiway program that allows you to communicate with devices via a Modbus. That's what I'm interested: this program can work in modbus slave mode via TCP or COM port.
How can this be repeated in c#? How to get a packet `0A 05 00 0DFF00 1C 82`from the master in the console via TCP or COM port?

The packet `0A 05 00 0DFF00 1C 82` means writing the 13th register of the Slave device No.10 (PC) to the "True" position. Detailed transcript [here](https://rapidscada.net/modbus/) (Modbus RTU, Request)...

I understand how to implement master mode using Easy Modbus.dll. I can't implement the slave mode. I was advised the NModbus library. At the moment without success:

```
check1
NModbus Slave Network ignoring request intended for NModbus Slave 1
```

Code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using NModbus;
using NModbus.Serial;

const string PrimarySerialPortName = "COM3";
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => cts.Cancel();

try
{
    await StartModbusSerialRtuSlaveNetwork(cts.Token);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();

return 0;

static async Task StartModbusSerialRtuSlaveNetwork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    
    using (SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(PrimarySerialPortName))
    {
        // configure serial port
        slavePort.BaudRate = 57600;
        slavePort.DataBits = 8;
        slavePort.Parity = Parity.None;
        slavePort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        slavePort.Open();

        IModbusFactory factory = new ModbusFactory();
        IModbusSlaveNetwork modbusSlaveNetwork = factory.CreateRtuSlaveNetwork(slavePort);

        slavePort.ReadTimeout = 100;
        slavePort.WriteTimeout = 500;

        //var acTechDataStore = new SlaveStorage();
        ISlaveDataStore dataStore = new NModbus.Data.SlaveDataStore();
        Console.WriteLine("check1");
        
        IModbusSlave slave10 = factory.CreateSlave(10);
        modbusSlaveNetwork.AddSlave(slave10);
        
        await modbusSlaveNetwork.ListenAsync(cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine("check2");

        await Task.Delay(1, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: You most likely want to use a library, But seeking recommendations for libraries or software is explicitly of topic for SO, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/